# Recursive Decompression of Strings

Tags: python

I'm trying to decompress strings using recursion. For example, the input:

**3[b3[a]]**

should output:

**baaabaaabaaa**

but I get:

**baaaabaaaabaaaabbaaaabaaaabaaaaa**

I have the following code but it is clearly off. The first find_end function works as intended. I am absolutely new to using recursion and any help understanding / tracking where the extra letters come from or any general tips to help me understand this really cool methodology would be greatly appreciated.

```
def find_end(original, start, level):
    if original[start] != "[":
        message = "ERROR in find_error, must start with [:", original[start:]
        raise ValueError(message)
    indent = level * "  "
    index = start + 1
    count = 1
    while count != 0 and index < len(original):
        if original[index] == "[":
            count += 1
        elif original[index] == "]":
            count -= 1
        index += 1
    if count != 0:
        message = "ERROR in find_error, mismatched brackets:", original[start:]
        raise ValueError(message)
    return index - 1


def decompress(original, level):
# set the result to an empty string
    result = ""
# for any character in the string we have not looked at yet
    for i in range(len(original)):
# if the character at the current index is a digit
        if original[i].isnumeric():
# the character of the current index is the number of repetitions needed
            repititions = int(original[i])
# start = the next index containing the '[' character
            x = 0
            while x < (len(original)):
                if original[x].isnumeric():
                    start = x + 1
                    x = len(original)
                else:
                    x += 1
# last = the index of the matching ']'
            last = find_end(original, start, level)
# calculate a substring using `original[start + 1:last]
            sub_original = original[start + 1 : last]
# RECURSIVELY call decompress with the substring
            # sub = decompress(original, level + 1)
# concatenate the result of the recursive call times the number of repetitions needed to the result
            result += decompress(sub_original, level + 1) * repititions
# set the current index to the index of the matching ']'
            i = last
# else
        else:
# concatenate the letter at the current index to the result
            if original[i] != "[" and original[i] != "]":
                result += original[i]
# return the result
    return result


def main():
    passed = True
    ORIGINAL = 0
    EXPECTED = 1
    # The test cases
    provided = [
        ("3[b]", "bbb"),
        ("3[b3[a]]", "baaabaaabaaa"),
        ("3[b2[ca]]", "bcacabcacabcaca"),
        ("5[a3[b]1[ab]]", "abbbababbbababbbababbbababbbab"),
    ]
    # Run the provided tests cases
    for t in provided:
        actual = decompress(t[ORIGINAL], 0)
        if actual != t[EXPECTED]:
            print("Error decompressing:", t[ORIGINAL])
            print("   Expected:", t[EXPECTED])
            print("   Actual:  ", actual)
            print()
            passed = False
    # print that all the tests passed
    if passed:
        print("All tests passed")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I gathered from your code, it probably gives the wrong result because of the approach you've taken to find the last matching closing brace at a given level (I'm not 100% sure, the code was a lot). However, I can suggest a cleaner approach using stacks (almost similar to DFS, without the complications):

```py
def decomp(s):
    stack = []
    for i in s:
        if i.isalnum():
            stack.append(i)
        elif i == "]":
            temp = stack.pop()
            count = stack.pop()
            if count.isnumeric():
                stack.append(int(count)*temp)
            else:
                stack.append(count+temp)
    for i in range(len(stack)-2, -1, -1):
        if stack[i].isnumeric():
            stack[i] = int(stack[i])*stack[i+1]
        else:
            stack[i] += stack[i+1]
    return stack[0]

print(decomp("3[b]"))          # bbb
print(decomp("3[b3[a]]"))      # baaabaaabaaa
print(decomp("3[b2[ca]]"))     # bcacabcacabcaca
print(decomp("5[a3[b]1[ab]]")) # abbbababbbababbbababbbababbbab
```

This works on a simple observation: rather tha evaluating a substring after on reading a `[`, evaluate the substring after encountering a `]`. That would allow you to build the result AFTER the pieces have been evaluated individually as well. (This is similar to the prefix/postfix evaluation using programming).
(You can add error checking to this as well, if you wish. It would be easier to check if the string is semantically correct in one pass and evaluate it in another pass, rather than doing both in one go)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution with the similar idea from above:
we go through string putting everything on stack until we find ']', then we go back until '[' taking everything off, find the number, multiply and put it back on stack

It's much less consuming as we don't add strings, but work with lists

Note: multiply number can't be more than 9 as we parse it as one element string

```
def decompress(string):

    stack = []
    letters = []

    for i in string:
        if i != ']':
            stack.append(i)
        elif i == ']':
            letter = stack.pop()
            while letter != '[':
                letters.append(letter)
                letter = stack.pop()

            word = ''.join(letters[::-1])
            letters = []

            stack.append(''.join([word for j in range(int(stack.pop()))]))

    return ''.join(stack)
```